# Stop audio when android activity loses focus

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play entry audio whenever Activity is running on foreground.
To do so id added audio file to raw directory and coded:

```
private MediaPlayer audio;

  @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
         audio= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.some_audio);
         audio.start();
       }
```

It works, but i want to stop audio when activity i quit activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
          audio.start();
        }
Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        audio.stop();

    }
```

App crashes, StackTrace mention error in MediaPlayer.create()

to avoid audio overlapping,I tried to set condition, if audio !playing then star audio:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        audio= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.some_audio); 
        Animator.start();
            if (!audio.isPlaying()) {
          audio.start();
        }
```

But none of that works.
How can i manage doing this to avoid audio overlapping ?

ps: Can someone please explain me why i got Error when declaring the following state in the **global scope**?

`private MediaPlayer audio=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.some_audio)`

Comment: create MediaPlayer in ocCreate, and use start and PAUSE in onResume  onPause

Answer (score 0):

initialize audio globally like

```
private MediaPlayer audio;
```

declare it in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    audio  = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audiofile);
    audio.start();
    .....
}
```

override onresume,onpause,onbackpressed,ondestroyed like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (audio!=null){
        audio.start();
    }else{
        audio = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audiofile);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (audio!=null && audio.isPlaying())
        audio.stop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (audio!=null && audio.isPlaying())
        audio.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (audio!=null && audio.isPlaying())
        audio.stop();
}
```

hope this helps . im also a beginner so forgive mistakes if any

Comment: Actually your code is pretty useful, it helped resolving the problem. Also, you could simply use : `if(audio==null) MediaPlayer audio=MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.audio_file)` instead of if/else statement. Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

stop() method will change state of to audio object to stopped, according to [android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#state-diagram), so you must set audio object as prepared before star(), simply by calling prepared() method.

```
    MediaPlayer audio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        audio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio_file);
         }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(audio==null) audio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio_file);
 // create method sets audio as prepared 
        audio.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(audio!=null && audio.isPlaying()) {
            audio.stop();
            try{
                audio.prepare();}
            catch(IllegalStateException | IOException e){
                //Exception handler
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }}}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(audio!=null && audio.isPlaying()) {
            audio.stop();
            try{
            audio.prepare();}
            catch(IllegalStateException | IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();    }}}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(audio!=null && audio.isPlaying()) audio.stop();
    }
```